# Is blocking an issue with greenlets?

Tags: python, asynchronous, nonblocking, green-threads, greenlets

I understand blocking code is a sin when it comes to event loops (i.e. NodeJS), but what about with greenlets (which I believe are green threads)? Is there an issue running code that calls blocking functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Greenlets themselves without an event loop as provided by gevent are [very primitive](http://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#motivation). A blocking call from within one greenlet will block all greenlets since greenlets alone have no capability to yield on IO operations, and no scheduler. Gevent's monkey-patching of socket and file IO is generally enough to enable non-blocking IO even with databases provided that the database library is written in python and uses sockets. Or alternately you can patch the library yourself.

Comment: Your example is a dead link. Could you please fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure that's what down-votes are for pal, but okay, it's your dime.

Answer (score 4):

Calling function that blocks event loop is of course issue, because other green threads will be waiting for end of this function.
But if you use [Gevent](http://gevent.org/) you can call blocking functions. Gevent patches common python blocking functions.
Write this at the start of program and Gevent will patch all blocking functions:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Comment: I was under the impression that green threads aren't the same thing as an event loop, and that calling blocking code in an event loop is a problem because it prevents all other requests from being processed. I wasn't sure whether calling blocking code when using greenlets would be an issue, such as blocking database calls. It seems that gevent monkey patches only blocking networking functions.

Comment: Database is different. 1) A request concurrent with a slow db request is usually also slow. Database throughput can soon decrease with number of connections. 2) A bad or slow network server should not block requests to other fast servers. Network paralellism usually increases throughput.